# IE11 in IE7mode not triggering mousewheel event

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer-7

I've not found the IE7 mode version of this specifically addressed. I've tried various versions of this, working fine in Chrome, FF, IE9+, but not in IE11 in forced IE7 mode, a client server-set requirement :-(.

IE7 mode alerts "mousewheel" as the wheelEvent , but never even calls first alert line of scrollHandler() on mouse wheel, so doesn't seem to be attaching the event/handler via window.attachEvent?

```
        var wheelEvent = "onwheel" in document.createElement("div") ? "wheel" : // Modern browsers support "wheel"
          document.onmousewheel !== undefined ? "mousewheel" : // Webkit and IE support at least "mousewheel"
          "DOMMouseScroll"; // let's assume that remaining browsers are older Firefox

    function scrollHandler(wheelEvent) {
        alert("scrollHandler "+wheelEvent);
        //upDown = -1 on scroll-down, = 1 on scroll up

            if (wheelEvent.wheelDelta) {//chrome
                upDown = (wheelEvent.wheelDelta % 120 - 0) == -0 ? wheelEvent.wheelDelta / 120 : wheelEvent.wheelDelta / 12;
            } else {//FF
                var rawAmmount = wheelEvent.deltaY ? wheelEvent.deltaY : wheelEvent.detail;
                upDown = -(rawAmmount % 3 ? rawAmmount * 10 : rawAmmount / 3);
            }
            scroller(upDown);       
    }

    if (window.addEventListener) {//most browsers
        window.addEventListener(wheelEvent, scrollHandler );
    }else if (window.attachEvent){//IE7...
        alert("IE7 - window.attachEvent: " + wheelEvent);
        window.attachEvent(wheelEvent, scrollHandler);
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[attachEvent](http://mdn.beonex.com/en/DOM/element.addEventListener.html#Legacy_Internet_Explorer_and_attachEvent) uses the *"on"* prefix for events, so you need to change your code to, and you need to attach the event to the document instead of window.

```
else if (window.attachEvent){//IE7...
   alert("IE7 - window.attachEvent: " + wheelEvent);
   document.attachEvent("on"+wheelEvent, scrollHandler);
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but I've tried this, and various explicit event strings -  window.attachEvent("onmousewheel", scrollHandler); - no luck, scrollHandler just never fires in IE11 in IE7 mode!

Comment: @alan.j.m It should be `document.attachEvent` apparently the window does not receive the onmousewheel event